# How to call scrapy in a python utillity

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to get data from the web in real-time and have used scrapy to extract the information to build a python utility. The problem is that the data is static while the information will change in time.

I wanted to know if it is viable to call my scrapy spider when the utility is invoked so that when the utility is called for the first time, the data at that time is stored as JSON with the user which will change when the user calls it the next time.

Please let me know if there is an alternative to it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit-1: To make it clear, the data that I have extracted will change over time. Here is a link to my previous question about building the spider: [How to scrape contents from multiple tables in a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064983/how-to-scrape-contents-from-multiple-tables-in-a-webpage). The problem is that as the league progresses, the fixtures' status will change (**completed** or **not yet completed**). I want the users to get real-time scraped data.

Edit-2: What I previously did was calling my spider separately and using the JSON generated for the purpose of my utillity. For the users to have real-time data, when they use it on the terminal, should I push the scrapy code into the main repository that will be uploaded to PyPI and call the spider in the main function of the .py file? Is this possible? What are its alternatives, if any?

Comment: "the data is static while the information will change in time"???

Comment: What I meant was that the data that I have extracted will change. (information in the web will change)

Comment: You'd find more support on SO if you provide an example of what you want to achieve, and even better if code that you tried

Comment: Your question is still a bit confusing.

If you asking if it is possible to have a scrapy spider run when a user performs a specific task in a user interface or automatically when a certain event occurs, then yes that is possible.

Comment: What I currently did was calling my spider separately and using the JSON generated for the utillity. For the users to have real-time data, when they use it on the terminal, the scrapy code also will have to be pushed into the main repository that will be uploaded to PyPI and call the spider in the main function of the .py file. Is this possible? What are its alternatives, if any?

Answer (score 0):

your could start your scrapy from code when you (or your user) need:

```
from scrapy import cmdline

SCRAPY_SPIDER_NAME = 'spyder_name'  # spyder name to start scraping
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl {}".format(SCRAPY_SPIDER_NAME))
```